# MySQL UNION stored procedure pivot tables

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to Union the results of 3 Stored Procedures.
The Procedures are coded the same but produce different results.

I have tried creating temporary tables within each procedure and UNION ALL on those within another procedure, but it is not giving me the expected results.

Thank you.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CONVERTOPCOLTOROWS;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE CONVERTOPCOLTOROWS (IN n_seq INT)
BEGIN 
SET @my_schema='femlinecycletime';
SET @my_table='table_seqcycletime';
SET @clause_where='`Seq`=';
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(my_query
    SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
INTO @sql FROM
    (SELECT
        CONCAT('SELECT', QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME), ' AS `KEY`, `', COLUMN_NAME, '` AS `value` FROM `', @my_table,'`WHERE ', @clause_where, n_seq) my_query
    FROM
        (SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` . `COLUMNS`
            WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = @my_schema
            AND `TABLE_NAME` = @my_table 
            AND `COLUMN_NAME` BETWEEN 'OP02' AND 'OP90') AS `col1`) AS `col2`;
            
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
End;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```